# Android:Updating recyclerview with new data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my app.First time when i open the fragment it makes an api request and update the recyclerview.When i again open the same fragment it will again make request and update the recycleview even when the data has been loaded previously.So to avoid this i have used a static boolean variable to check whether data has been loaded or not.So this avoid repetitive network calls but suppose i am using the app and the data has been loaded but if the data is changed from backend server it wont reflect in my app as the boolean variable would be set true at first loading and wont make any other api calls.
So what is the standard approach for this.

Comment: Check push notifications, to let your devices know that new data is available and the connection has to be done again.

Comment: @Android jack : post your code something about what you did

Comment: @Android jack attach time stamp with response if it is predefined that data will be change after this much time compare first time stamp and then make api call furthermore whether you are using any networking library?

Comment: @Jai: i have already mentioned what i have tried.I am not asking for readymade code but for a standard procedure to follow.Everytime we just cant post the code it would be too lengthy to post.

Comment: agree with @zozelfelfo. Push notification is the correct way to get new data if something changes at backend.

Comment: @zozelfelfo: Thanks for the reply.Apart from push notifications is there any other way as it would make my simple app very complex.Anyways thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Since somebody already mentioned here you can use push notification to notify your app that some change has occurred in the data from backend and you can hit the api again to update the data. You can check out [this link](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/push-dont-poll-how-to-use-gcm-to-update-app-data/)

Other than that you can always keep track of the time when your last network call was made. If the time exceeds X number of hours/days then you can hit the API again. 
Hope this answers your query.